# how to make code on openMP work on xeon phi?

Tags: algorithm, openmp, prims-algorithm, xeon-phi

everyone. Hope someone will help me. I have a code to parallel the Prim's algorithm on openMP and I need to make it work on Xeon Phi. Please, help me. I cannot really understand how to do this. Here is my code on openMP.

```
void ParallelPrim(double *pMatrix, TTreeNode** pMinSpanningTree, int Size)
{
    int LastAdded;
    TGraphNode NearestNode;
    TGraphNode **NotInMinSpanningTree = new TGraphNode* [Size-1];
    LastAdded = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < Size-1; i++)
{
    NotInMinSpanningTree[i] = new TGraphNode;
    NotInMinSpanningTree[i]->NodeNum = i+1;
    NotInMinSpanningTree[i]->Distance = -1.0f;
    NotInMinSpanningTree[i]->ParentNodeNum = -1;
}

for(int Iter = 1; Iter < Size; Iter++)
{
    #pragma omp parallel for 
        for(int i = 0; i < Size-1; i++)
            if(NotInMinSpanningTree[i] != NULL)
            {
                double t1 = NotInMinSpanningTree[i]->Distance;
                double t2 = pMatrix[(NotInMinSpanningTree[i]->NodeNum) * Size + LastAdded];
                if(((t1 < 0) && (t2 > 0)) || (t1>0) && (t2 > 0) && (t1 > t2))
                {
                    NotInMinSpanningTree[i]->Distance = t2;
                    NotInMinSpanningTree[i]->ParentNodeNum = LastAdded;
                }
            }

        NearestNode.NodeNum = -1;
        NearestNode.Distance = 3000;
#pragma omp parallel
        {
            TGraphNode ThreadNearestNode;
            ThreadNearestNode.NodeNum = -1;
            ThreadNearestNode.Distance = 3000;
            #pragma omp for 
                for(int i = 0; i < Size-1; i++)
                {
                if(NotInMinSpanningTree[i] != NULL)
                {
                    double t1 = NotInMinSpanningTree[i]->Distance;
                    double t2 = ThreadNearestNode.Distance;
                    if((t1 > 0) && (t1 < t2) )
                    {
                        ThreadNearestNode.Distance = t1;
                        ThreadNearestNode.NodeNum = NotInMinSpanningTree[i]->NodeNum;
                    }
                }
            }
#pragma omp critical
            {
                if(ThreadNearestNode.Distance < NearestNode.Distance)
                {
                    NearestNode.Distance = ThreadNearestNode.Distance;
                    NearestNode.NodeNum = ThreadNearestNode.NodeNum;
                }
            }
        }
        pMinSpanningTree[NearestNode.NodeNum] = new TTreeNode;

        pMinSpanningTree[NearestNode.NodeNum]->NodeNum = NotInMinSpanningTree[NearestNode.NodeNum-1]->ParentNodeNum;
        pMinSpanningTree[NearestNode.NodeNum]->Distance = NearestNode.Distance;

        int Parent = NotInMinSpanningTree[NearestNode.NodeNum-1]->ParentNodeNum;
        if(pMinSpanningTree[Parent] != NULL)
        {
           TTreeNode *tmp = new TTreeNode;
            tmp->Distance = NearestNode.Distance;
            tmp->NodeNum = NearestNode.NodeNum;
        }
        else
        {
            pMinSpanningTree[Parent] = new TTreeNode;
            pMinSpanningTree[Parent]->Distance = NearestNode.Distance;
            pMinSpanningTree[Parent]->NodeNum = NearestNode.NodeNum;
        }
        LastAdded = NearestNode.NodeNum;
        delete NotInMinSpanningTree[NearestNode.NodeNum - 1];
        NotInMinSpanningTree[NearestNode.NodeNum - 1] = NULL;
    }
    delete[] NotInMinSpanningTree;
}
```

Comment: How are you compiling this? Compiler, flags, OS...

Comment: Also, have a look at [this presentation](http://www.cism.ucl.ac.be/XeonPhi.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

You have two basic options for running your code on the Intel Xeon Phi coprocessor. You can compile your entire program with the -mmic and -qopenmp flags and then run it using either micnativeloadex or by copying the executable and required libraries over to the coprocessor with scp. Alternately, you can omit the -mmic and instead modify your code so the portion of the code you want to run on the coprocessor falls inside an offload section where just that portion of code will be sent to the coprocessor to run and the remainder of the code will run on host.

The presentation Avi sent you to is a lovely overview of programming for the coprocessor. In addition you can find basic information on compiling and optimizing for the coprocessor at: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/programming-and-compiling-for-intel-many-integrated-core-architecture.

HOWEVER, and this is a big however, your code does not vectorize and has significant serial sections. To obtain optimum performance on the coprocessor, your code must both vectorize and parallelize.